# mcmire/active_campaign - "Contact Email Address is not valid."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

With gem 'active_campaign', '0.1.9', I was getting error on contact_add method call

```
response = ActiveCampaign.contact_add(email: params[:email], :"p[1]" => 1)
{"result_code"=>0, "result_message"=>"Contact Email Address is not valid.", "result_output"=>"json", "results"=>[]}
```

Which was resolved in this branch (check the last commit)- > https://github.com/mcmire/active_campaign/tree/add-missing-header

But if I try to install this gem via GitHub and branch -

```
gem 'active_campaign', :github => 'mcmire/active_campaign', :branch => 'add-missing-header'
```

I get an error with an active_campaign initializer file which was not there before -

config/initializers/active_campaign.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method`api_endpoint=' for ActiveCampaign:Module (NoMethodError)

```
Content of active_campaign.rb
ActiveCampaign.api_endpoint=ENV['ACTIVECAMPAIGN_ENDPOINT']
ActiveCampaign.api_key=ENV['ACTIVECAMPAIGN_API_KEY']
```

So I am getting an error with initializer file if I switch gem version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your initializer to the following:

```
ActiveCampaign.configure do |config|
  config.api_endpoint = ENV['ACTIVECAMPAIGN_ENDPOINT']
  config.api_key=ENV['ACTIVECAMPAIGN_API_KEY']
end
```

Hope this helps!